# Play a specific track of a playlist in a Sonos Group

Tags: sonos

I would like to load a playlist to a Sonos Group and play a specific track from this playlist.

Using this api I can load a playlist and play the first track

```
POST /groups/{groupId}/playlists 

{
  "playlistId" : "1",
  "playOnCompletion" : true,
  "action" : "REPLACE"
}
```

but how can I play a specific track of this playlist?